# Jetty configuration to disable all SSL checks

Tags: ssl, jetty

There is certain Tomcat [listener implementation](http://code.google.com/p/xebia-france/wiki/AcceptAllSslCertificatesListener) that disable all SSL checks. This comes very handy in development environment. Is there any way to config Jetty to the same behavior?

Answer (score 1):

> This comes very handy in development environment

Actually it doesn't so much 'come in handy' as present an unacceptable security risk that this configuration will be deployed in production. There is no point in having business-critical differences between your test and production environments. Don't do this. Solve the problems. You need the solutions and you don't need the insecure configuration.